# Crash [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:] on ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've crashed app when my app run on iOS 7

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3b67718c'

I'm using the code on my project

```
- (instancetype)initWithLocale:(NSLocale *)locale andFirstWeekday:(NSUInteger)firstWeekday{
    if (self = [super init]){
        _calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        _calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        _calendar.locale = locale;
        _calendar.firstWeekday = firstWeekday;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Someone guy please help me to solve that problem that help me save a ton of time in my life. Thanks.

Comment: Use `_calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];` you might be running in iOS < 8.0 the method is available in iOS 8.

Comment: `+calendarWithIdentifier:` is available since iOS 8.0+, that's why it crashes on iOS7, while `-initWithCalendarIdentifier:` is available since iOS2. Use `-initWithCalendarIdentifier:` (with an `alloc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier]` is available for iOS 8+.

You can use initializer method instead, this works fine in all iOS:

```
_calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
```